# android media player - setting up with song selection

Tags: android, media-player, environment

My project has a button. Each time the button is clicked I want to assign a new song to the media player. I'm running into error: cannot resolve method 'setDatSource(java.io.File)'

```
final MediaPlayer mPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bass);

   b.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

            }catch(Exception  e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the new song that you want to set? Also return true in the onLongClick method so that your touch gets consumed.

Comment: I initially want the user to assign a song before the media player will play anything. The purpose of this button is to assign a song to a media player each time it's used.